# count unique character values for different col of character values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm looking to count how many unique `gene` there are for each unique `group`, following the dput() example below.

I've tried

```
library(tidyverse)
example %>% 
  group_by(group,gene) %>% 
  mutate(total = n()) %>%
  unique() -> count.viz
```

and

```
example %>% 
  select(gene) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(total = n()) %>%
  unique() -> count.viz
```

But I think that's just counting how many times each unique gene appears, regardless of the group.  My ideal output `count.viz` would have a new column `total` where for group "Amino acid metabolism" and "Carbohydrate metabolism" `total` would equal 2 while "Translation" and "Membrane transport" `total` would equal 1.

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(KO = c("K00639", "K12308", "K01881", "K16785", 
"K03639", "K00174"), Project = c("Ga0598246", "Ga0598246", "Ga0598246", 
"Ga0598246", "Ga0598246", "Ga0598246"), count = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.0170424288146159), gene = c("kbl, GCAT", "bgaB, lacA", "PARS, proS", 
"ecfT", "moaA, CNX2", "korA, oorA, oforA"), group = c("Amino acid metabolism", 
"Carbohydrate metabolism", "Translation", "Membrane transport", 
"Amino acid metabolism", "Carbohydrate metabolism")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    Project = "Ga0598246", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your example data included a case where the same group has two identical values for gene - currently there are no such cases so it's hard to demonstrate that the unique constraint is met.

Comment: The "Amino acid metabolism" has two unique genes "kbl, GCAT" and "moaA, CNX2", so this category's "total" should be 2. I apologize if this isn't clear.

Comment: What I mean is, if your data doesn't have an example with two _identical_ genes in the same group, then solutions won't be able to disambiguate between a two count for two unique genes (correct) and a two-count for two repeat genes (incorrect).

Comment: Please, see my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You don't need `unique()`  call. Everything will be done using grouping instead.

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  group_by(group, gene) %>% 
  summarise(total = n())
```

**Edited** upon clarification from the OP comment:

```
example %>% 
  distinct(group, gene) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(total = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
example %>%
    separate_rows(gene) %>%
    ungroup() %>% # seems your `example` is already grouped by `Project`
    summarise(total = length(unique(gene)), .by = group)
```

and you will obtain

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  group                   total
  <chr>                   <int>
1 Amino acid metabolism       4
2 Carbohydrate metabolism     5
3 Translation                 2
4 Membrane transport          1
```